# How to specify a trigger function to execute only when there are records in a table?

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am using postgres 10.9. I created a trigger function and trigger on a table after insert. Now when I insert a record, it gives me error because initially there is no data in the table

Error: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

How can I make sure that the function executes only when there are records in the table?

Trigger function-

```
create or replace function delete_old_token()
returns trigger as
$body$
begin
delete from token where timestamp < NOW() - interval '1 day';
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Trigger-

```
create trigger delete_token
after insert
on token
for each row
execute procedure delete_old_token();
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with an empty table, it's caused by an invalid trigger function: you forgot the `return` statement.

As you are using that for an `AFTER` trigger the actual return *value* is irrelevant, but you need to return something.

```
create or replace function delete_old_token()
  returns trigger as
$body$
begin
  delete from token where timestamp < NOW() - interval '1 day';
  return null; --<<< here
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: ohh yes! Thanks for helping!